# How bc implement image resizing this much perfectly?

Tags: java, struts2

I have worked in java i need to resize proportionally as BC resizing images using `fill_proportional algorithm`. When U need resizing I have gone through different option and exact solution i am getting from BC, here they resize image that fit to layout. [Click here to see BC comments](http://www.roomthree.com.au/_blog/Roomthree-Blog/post/dynamically-resizing-web-app-images-in-business-catalyst/). The solution on the above link is perfect and I am looking for the similar solution in java. So can anybody suggest me a solution in java to create an image that fill in a particular area like the link above?

Comment: Are you wanting to do this in a BC website? BC doesn't run java OR are you looking to do what BC does in java?

Comment: I need a similar functionality in java. I just need the same logic implement in java.

Comment: why don't you use `jquery` and `javascript` to work with Business Catalyst? [Getting Started with jQuery & BC](http://www.businesscatalyst.com/bc-blog/getting_started_with_jquery_bc)

Comment: No i am not using bc for my development purpose. I am using java. i need to implement the similar functionality in java.